# 'Open in new tab' option doesn't appear for links in safari for ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari

I have a webapp with links like that:

```
<a href="/articles/">Articles</a>
```

That I am controlling with js inside my app:

```
  $(document).on("click", 'a', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href) {
      window.app.navigate(href, {trigger: true});
    }
  });
```

All is working properly on desktop, if new user simply clicks in the link it's opened through js and if the user clicks the right button over the link can select the option 'Open in new tab' and it's working.

The problem is that in Safari (ios) if I press for a second over the link don't appear any option...

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution, it was not working because of the css property **-webkit-touch-callout** that was as 'none' instead of 'default'.

```
-webkit-touch-callout: default;
```

That solved my problem!